# Почему из поиска Google ответ на stackoverflow.com открывается в приложении?

Tags: android

Пытаюсь понять, почему из результатов поиска Google ответы на stackovervlow.com сразу открываются в приложении? Хочу в своем приложении сделать также.

В документации это очень похоже на App Links. Но, чтобы ссылка открывалась в приложении без вопросов, необходима [automatic verification](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#request-verify). Я ее не нахожу ни в приложении (соответствующий фрагмент манифеста ниже), ни на сайте (https://stackoverflow.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json возвращает 404, хотя я бы ожидал там [встретить файл](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#web-assoc)).

Как они это сделали?

```
<activity android:name="com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.LinkDispatchActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/questions/" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/q/" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/a/" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/users/" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/u/" />
        <data android:path="/" />
        <data android:host="stackoverflow.com" />
        <data android:host="meta.stackoverflow.com" />
        <data android:host="serverfault.com" />
        <data android:host="meta.serverfault.com" />
        <data android:host="superuser.com" />
        <data android:host="meta.superuser.com" />
        <data android:host="stackapps.com" />
        <data android:host="askubuntu.com" />
        <data android:host="meta.askubuntu.com" />
        <data android:host="mathoverflow.net" />
        <data android:host="meta.mathoverflow.net" />
        <data android:host="*.stackexchange.com" />
        <data android:host="pt.stackoverflow.com" />
        <data android:host="ja.stackoverflow.com" />
        <data android:host="ru.stackoverflow.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного не так. Это фича поиска Google. Для настройки поиска, во-первых нужен App Links, во-вторых, Indexing. Смотреть здесь https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html

Сам по себе App Links предоставляет возможность открыть ваше и другие приложения (без autoverify) из любого места если у них в манифесте есть action VIEW и category BROWSABLE (ну и фильтр по хостам и схемам подходит). В частности в том  же google поиске есть и обычные ссылки на so, для которых можно выбрать в каком приложении открывать. Вот если бы autoverify было бы настроено, как вы ожидали, то выбора бы не было и открывалось бы все автоматом.